# Count how many files exist on system?

Tags: filesystem

Is there a way to count how many files/folders exist on the system?

Even better if i could get the list into a csv file?

Comment: you mean, given a folder, count files inside it?

Comment: Sorry but I somehow miss the point of this. You are aware that there are virtual file systems like proc and sys are mounted as well? If you want to validate contents of directories use check sums and programs like md5deep.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if my idea is the most elegant, but it works:

```
tree / | tail -1 > output
```

It will take a while until the tree will finish, but you will get a number of directories and a number of files, in your file "output".

Answer (score 1):

The following command will output how many files and folders are present under `/` on your system.

```
 echo `find  / . -type d -print 2> /dev/null | wc -l` directories and `find  / . -type f -print 2> /dev/null | wc -l` files are present on this system.
```

Answer (score 0):

Type in a terminal:

```
cd /    
find -type f | wc -l
```

Comment: will this get all paths? So for file  /directory/file.filetype it will return /directory  as well as /directory/file.filetype?

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -Rtl / | grep -v ^$ | wc -l
```

This will list all the dirs and files on the system.

The another good way to do this is to use find.

```
find / -type f | wc -l
```

What list you want to take into CSV file?

Comment: I would like to import into a csv file a list of all possible paths on the system. so /directory, as well as /directory/file.filetype